# Workflow stuck Browser enabled InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a task which is assigned to me. When I open the task and click on the hyperlink to fill in the browser-based form. But then when the form closes I get the task with a button stating *"put task to done"*.

[image]

When I click on the finish task it get's stuck It stays in an endless loop.

[image]

Does anybody know how I can get out of this loop, or how this is happening?

Edit: Here is my workflow:

[image]

This workflow is split up into 2 tasks first it goes to the secretary who then decides to who the request should be sent to. Then a new task is assigned to the manager.

[image]

Comment: What is the workflow, can you share the Workflow image as well..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't create 2 separate "Assign To" tasks, just make it ONE assign to secretary, and ONE assign to manager, make 1 if condition at the beginning of the workflow to check the location, and save the values of the secretary and manager in a variable, and always assign the task to these variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mohamed, I added the SP designer workflow to clarify a little. My apologies for the language (dutch). Let me just explain the flow: 1) assigned to secretary the secretary then fills in a field in the form stating to whom the task should be assigned to (this can change everytime) when she finishes the task 2)the assigned person gets his task and has to approve or reject and complete his task. (both times it's stuck in the loop) something with Webview? I don't really believe its a Workflow problem more a IE10 or trusted sites issue...

Comment: Which loop are we talking about here? Isn't it a straight process? Would you try with InfoPath Client instead of Browser Form?

Comment: I also tried with infoPath Client that works better on my laptop but some how on another laptop it won't work... I'll investigate that a little more

Comment: I tried using the Client but I don't have InfoPath filler on each computer so I rather use Browser. It must be something to do with the Previous page not being there. It wants to redirect me to the Previous page but it just doesn't know what page that is. If I click the Previous page link it shows me a "not found" screen.